# Is it recommended to generate recurring "elements" with javascript in the sense of DRY?

Tags: javascript, html, dry

Is it recommended to generate recurring "elements" with javascript in the sense of "don't repeat yourself"?

For example, every link in application contains "#/".
Is it better to write every single time in the href-attribute or should I get use of JavaScript and let it do something like:
JavaScript, prepend in every href-attribute a string "#/"?

And in which cases shouldn't I use JavaScript and get rid of my laziness?

Comment: This question is opinion based.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and the answer will vary from case to case. When you say web application and you're talking about links, it's a good idea to keep a sort of "base URL" server-side and construct your hyperlinks with it. I'm not in favor of hard-coding stuff and especially with strings you need to be as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find DRY very applicable to javascript code, but not so applicable on the client-side for static HTML because everything will perform better if you just spell out the multiple copies of static HTML, even if stuff is repeated.

If you want to practice DRY in the source HTML, then the place to do that is with a templating language on the server-side so your can define one construct there and have the server expand that N times.

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy has is costs. In your example using javascript will require the browser to add an `href="#/"` to all a-elements. This costs some CPU (depending on the size of your page) and will slow down page rendering. For that situation I would suggest to type in the href yourself into the HTML.